# Can a solid be both crystalline and amorphous?

Tags: terminology, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography, glass, ceramics

The first line in the [Wikipedia article for "Glass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass) reads:

> Glass is a **non-crystalline amorphous** solid that is often transparent and has widespread practical, technological, and decorative usage in, for example, window panes, tableware, and optoelectronics.
>
> <sub>Emphasis, mine.</sub>

From what I've been taught at school, if a solid is *amorphous* then it is **necessarily** *non-crystalline* and *vice versa*. (Of course, you could convert a given sample of an amorphous solid to some crystalline form...but it would no longer be amorphous now would it?).

The "*non-crystalline amorphous*" pleonasm adopted by Wikipedia seems to suggest the existence of (yes, I know this sounds stupid) *crystalline amorphous* solids.

Can something (I'm using glass as an example) be *both* "crystalline" **and** "amorphous?"

If not (as I suspect is the case), then why does Wikipedia use the pleonasm "non-crystalline amorphous" when describing glass? Is it purely for emphasis?

---

Yes, I've already seen [this question here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48735/), and no, my question's not a dupe of that.

Sure, it's possible to convert an amorphous solid to a crystalline solid (proper melting and cooling should do it), I'm not questioning *that*.

What I *am* questioning, is whether a **crystalline amorphous** solid can exist. For example, glass has both (non-crystalline) amorphous  and crystalline (non-amorphous) phases.... but does it have **crystalline amorphous** phases? Yes? No? Why?

Comment: Here is an amorphous crystal https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal (look in the first images)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does crystalline glass exist?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48735/does-crystalline-glass-exist)

Comment: Maybe you can say " amorphous crystal" because it has some periodic arrangements but they are lost in the distance. You can find this on Wikipedia also: amorphous (from the Greek a, without, morphé, shape, form) or non-crystalline solid is a solid that lacks the long-range order that is characteristic of a crystal.

Comment: This seems to be a question on English usage more then Chemistry. I prefer the Wikipedia phrase since it emphasizes the difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about semantics

Comment: @Jon Eh? No... "Can something be both crystalline and amorphous?" doesn't sound like an English usage question. People seem to  be missing this point, which is why I paraphrased my question (see under **EDIT**) ;P

Comment: So what do you call a quasi-crystal? It would be a non-crystalline, non-amorphous solid, perhaps. Again, at best you are questioning somebody else's phrasing.

Comment: @Mith No, it isn't about semantics. Re-read the question again please (The "terminolgy" tag must be blacklisted then if you're right) O:)

Comment: @Jon I want to know: Do amorphous crystalline solids **exist**? (an example would be nice too)

Comment: Well, if you'd knew more about semantics, you wouldn't ask it in the way you did. Putting 2 similar description together, may or may not be redundant and even if is still may be useful. I'm quite against turning the site into "translate this passage for me 'cause I'm not getting the point" as happens on other sites.

Comment: @Mithoron But "non-crystalline amorphous" **is** redundant and useless (another pleonasm) :/

Comment: How do you feel about 'non-glassy amorphous solid'? If you think that is redundant and useless you would be incorrect. So, yes, the phrasing is overly precise - not exactly a crime in science.

Comment: @paracetamol I edited to add clarity. I think this question could be reopened, but I want to make sure I understand what is being asked.